# How Can I Avoid Using Magic Strings in my MVC CustomModelBinding?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reflection, model-binding

I have a method that determines the concrete type to instantiate for an abstract type based on the value of a property:

```
private static Type GetModelType(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
{
    if (modelType != typeof(MyAbstractClass)) return modelType;

    var key = "MyAbstractClass.ConcreteTypeEnum";
    if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(key))
    {
        var concreteTypeName = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key).AttemptedValue;
        modelType = Type.GetType(
          $"{modelType.Namespace}.{concreteTypeName}, {modelType.Assembly}" );
        }
    }
    return modelType;
}
```

How can I (using reflection, probably) determine the name of the property `"MyAbstractClass.ConcreteTypeEnum"` without using a string to find it?  If someone renames the property I don't want my modelbinding to break.

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
var key = modelType.GetProperty(t => t.ConcreteTypeEnum).Name
```

... but no such critter exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nameof` to get the property and class name as string. This way if you get compile time safety e.g. when renaming the class or property. Use it like so:

```
var propertyName = nameof(MyAbstractClass.ConcreteTypeEnum); 
// propertyName is now "ConcreteTypeEnum"
var className = nameof(MyAbstractClass);
// className is now "MyAbstractClass"
```

Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof

Comment: Well tie me to a hog and roll me in the mud.  I wouldn't have thought this would work, since `ConcreteTypeEnum` isn't static... but it does!